# Serverless: Deploy to same api from different yml

Tags: node.js, aws-api-gateway, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

I have api `api.demo`

It has following structure

```
api.demo
   /service1:
     GET /test1
     GET /test2
     ...
  /service2
     GET /test1
     GET /test2
     ...
```

I have two separate folders `service1, service2`
Each one having its own serverless.yml file
When I deploy It creates tow separate api's in api gateway as below

```
api.demo(id1)
   /service1:
     GET /test1
     GET /test2
     ...
api.demo(id2)
   /service2
     GET /test1
     GET /test2
```

How to update service2 to take same api endpoint api.demo(id1)?

How I can achieve this?
Any pointers would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a custom domain name: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-custom-domains.html

You can map base path to an API, so you could map `/service1` to the first API and `/service2` to the second API. Clients would be hitting a custom domain name rather than the default `execute-api` endpoint that we provide.

Answer (score 0):

In main service:

```
resources:
  Outputs:
    ApiGatewayRestApiId:
      Value:
        Ref: ApiGatewayRestApi
      Export:
        Name: prod-ApiGatewayRestApiId

    ApiGatewayRestApiRootResourceId:
      Value:
         Fn::GetAtt:
          - ApiGatewayRestApi
          - RootResourceId 
      Export:
        Name: prod-ApiGatewayRestApiRootResourceId
```

In secondary service:

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs8.10
  stage: dev
  region: us-east-1

  apiGateway:
    restApiId:
      'Fn::ImportValue': prod-ApiGatewayRestApiId
    restApiRootResourceId:
      'Fn::ImportValue': prod-ApiGatewayRestApiRootResourceId
```

Source: https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/api-gateway-domains-across-services.html

Answer (score -1):

https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/services/

> **Note:** Currently, every service will create a separate REST API on AWS API Gateway. Due to a limitation with AWS API Gateway, you can only have a custom domain per one REST API. If you plan on making a large REST API, please make note of this limitation. Also, a fix is in the works and is a top priority.

The in-progress fix can be [tracked here](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/3078).

The [relevant forum thread](http://forum.serverless.com/t/multiple-services-behind-a-single-api-gateway/191) has a few suggestions. Probably the easiest is to have an extra API gateway that delegates to the real gateways, 
either through

- HTTP redirects
- proxying to the other API
- duplicating the api (direct linking to whatever lambda sits behind the real API gateway)

None of those options are without flaws, though.